# Como saber a data de cada registro que foi inserido no banco de dados?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Boa tarde!

Tenho um pequeno banco de dados que armazena o registro de várias pessoas. Infelizmente não foi criado um comportamento para registrar a data e horário do registro salvo no banco de dados.

É possível descobrir a data e horário em que o registro foi inserido no banco de dados?

Eu tentei usar esse comando:

`select TABLE_NAME, CREATE_TIME from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = ''`

Mas mostra somente a data da última atualização na tabela mas eu preciso da data de cada registro da tabela.

Conto com a ajuda de vocês, muito obrigado. (:

Comment: Pode criar uma trigger para alterar os valores de duas colunas como `criado_em` e `ultima_atualizacao`

Comment: Boa tarde, obrigado pela resposta, poderia demonstrar/ensinar como faço essa trigger?

Comment: Eu recomendaria tu fazer salvar a data pela sua aplicação e não por trigger. As tabelas que tu precisa saber a data que foi inserido/atualizado tu inseri uma coluna nessa tabela pra guardar a data de inserção/atualização, e na hora de inserir um novo registro tu envia a data junto.

Comment: Mas ele quer resgatar a data e hora dos registros que já estão salvos de determinada tabela que não possui nenhum campo registrando data e hora.

Comment: @VictorCarnaval Nesse caso não tem como.

Answer (score 2):

É uma boa prática em sistemas comerciais manter um log de operações(quem/ fez o que/ quando), isso lhe dá a possibilidade de fazer:

- Uma auditoria em seu sistema em caso de solicitação direta ou judicial.
- Levantamento do histórico de operação. Seu caso.
- Obter informação complementar para restauração parcial de backup devido a mal uso do sistema.

Quanto a situação em que você se encontra **talvez** o sistema interno de logs do SQL possa lhe salvar.

[Log binário](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log.html) é um conjunto de arquivos de log que contém informações sobre as modificações nos dados feitas na instancia do servidor MySql.

O log é habilitado iniciando o servidor com a opção `--log-bin`. Então a primeira coisa que você tem que fazer é verificar como que o seu servidor inicializa a instancia do MySql. Normalmente em instancias corporativas ou provimento web essa opção é selecionada. Em caso de servidores domésticos ou small office normalmente essa opção é dispensada.

Caso você nunca tenha usado opção `--log-bin` eu sinto muito mas essas datas são irrecuperáveis.

Mas caso você tenha sorte todas as operações de sua firma tenham sido logadas entre no shell do mysql e digite:

```
mysql> SHOW BINARY LOGS;
```

Esse comando exibirá o conjunto de arquivos de logs de operação do MySql:

```
+---------------+-----------+
| Log_name      | File_size |
+---------------+-----------+
| binlog.000015 |    724935 |
| binlog.000016 |    733481 |
+---------------+-----------+
```

Para saber qual o diretório em que se encontra esses arquivos digite:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';

+---------------+---------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                       |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------+
| datadir       | C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\ |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Vá para esse diretório e use a ferramenta [mysqlbinlog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html) para ler o conteúdo dos logs:

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\> mysqlbinlog binlog.000015
```

[image: uma linha do binlog]

Cada operação registrada começa com a data no formato `ddyymm` e hora.